# How to add click event listener to infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, modal-dialog, listener, infowindow

i'm developing my first web application using Google Maps Javascript API v3 (with markers clustering libraries). Here is part of my code:

```
var markersReady = [];    
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            icon : 'images/marker.png',
        });
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent("<div id='info'><p id='title'>" + data.title + "</p><p>" + data.desc + "</p></div>");
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
        markersReady.push(marker);
    }
```

As you can see i add an event listener to every marker to make them clickable. When users click on one of them, it shows the infoWindow. Now how to add an event listener to the infoWindow as well? I'm using Bootstrap and i want to show a modal when user click on infoWindow popup. In addition, how to pass parameters to modal so every modal shows info according to the clicked marker?

Comment: Im sure if your 'data.desc' contains HTML code that triggers the modal window on a href for instance, all you would need is the modal window code on the main page.

Comment: `data.desc` does not contains HTML, it comes from JSON file and it contains a string. How to trigger modal (that i add on main page) and pass to it the custom data of every marker?

Comment: All you need to do is make the marker clickable. So in your marker options define `clickable: true`.